# Wget Folder in Bash

Tags: bash, ftp, download, directory, wget

I'm trying to use wget in bash to get a folder from my ftp host, but when I download the files it makes new folders for the folder that I'm downloading. For example, when I use this script to download my folder:

```
wget -r "ftp://$USER:$PASS@example.com/subdomains/cydia/httpdocs/theme/themes/$theme_root"
```

It creates a folder called "example.com" then within that one it makes "subdomains" and so on. I just want it to download the `$theme_root` folder that I'm downloading into the folder that I used cd to get into (/theme_builder/themes). Sorry if I'm not explaining this well but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -nH --cut-dirs=4 -r url
```

I hope, than counted right... if not, change the 4 to another number.

Comment: That worked great, and it made the whole process faster some how. It was 5 though

Comment: I'm not sure, since I don't have a ftp url to test with, but you might want to look at the `-P` option, which places things in a folder.

Comment: shamelessly stealing a comment from another so answer: Better use wget -m (--mirror). wget -r is limited to a recursion depth of 5 by default.